# How to python logging as Cosmos-DB logger?

Tags: python

If I consider cosmos-db as my logger. Can I create a custom handler/logger of CosmosDB and enforce python logger to it? Like we can do for FileHandler and control log level from dictConfig.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
import logging
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient, PartitionKey

class CosmosDBHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, connection_str: str, database_name: str, container_name: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.client = CosmosClient.from_connection_string(connection_str)
        self.database = self.client.create_database_if_not_exists(database_name)
        self.container = self.database.create_container_if_not_exists(
            container_name,
            partition_key=PartitionKey(path="/level")
        )

    def emit(self, record):
        log_entry = self.format(record)
        item_body = {
            'id': str(record.created),
            'level': record.levelname,
            'message': log_entry,
            'name': record.name
        }
        self.container.upsert_item(body=item_body)

# Usage
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

handler = CosmosDBHandler(
    connection_str='your_cosmos_db_connection_string',
    database_name='your_database_name',
    container_name='your_container_name'
)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.info('This is a test log message.')
```